# Enable button when a variable is a specific value

Tags: flash, variables, button, actionscript, actionscript-2

I'm making a game with AS2.

Recently I coded a lot on Unity but I don't get how I recreate the `void Update()` function.

For example, I got this script:

```
stop();

if(Points == 0){
    myButton.enabled = true;
    } else {
        myButton.enabled = false;
        }
```

The problem is that this only executes only once, and if the variable `Points` is 0, it won't enable the button.

Comment: You should learn AS3. This version of the code is more adapted and more efficient, particulary for a game...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the condition `Points == 0` corresponding exactly at `myButton.enabled`,
you can symplify your code like that:

```
myButton.enabled = Points == 0;
```

Put your code into a function `btEnabled()` that will be invoked where your variable Points will be incremented (enterFrame or onPress on a button).

```
function btEnabled():Void {
    myButton.enabled = Points == 0;
}
```

I ignore your code, but onPress could give something like that:

```
var Points:Number = -2;

more.onPress = function():Void {
    Points++;
    btEnabled();
}
less.onPress = function():Void {
    Points--;
    btEnabled();
}

function btEnabled():Void {
    myButton.enabled = Points == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to invoke code repeatedly on tick or every frame, in AS2 this is achieved with [onEnterFrame](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001329.html).
However, it may be a better idea just to set the enabled property of 'myButton' when you set the variable 'Points' to 0.